# How do I attach ragdolls to other objects?

Tags: half-life-2, hammer

I'm trying to make ragdolls attach to posts in the Source Hammer Editor for Half-Life 2. The outcome would be something like what is in the Sandtraps chapter, with the Combine guard used as a dummy:

[image]

This is the best I could find without going in-game.
Image source:

I did some research a while ago, but what I tried (which I do not remember what it was) did not work. The problem I am facing at the moment is how to actually attach the ragdoll to the post.

EDIT 1: I have tried using `phys_ragdollmagnet`, but to no avail. I have also tried sticking a prop through the ragdoll and into the post, but that doesn't work either.

EDIT 2: I have figured out how to attach objects using `phys_ragdollconstraint` and `phys_constraintsystem`. Now the problem is, I can't get them to stop dancing! They keep jiggling even though I have disabled the collisions on the ragdolls.

Comment: We had a hanging ragdoll in one of our old maps. That might do the trick, if I can still find it... unfortunately it was like 10 years ago.

Comment: @dly I had thought about using ropes and constraints like a noose (grim, I know), but I didn't want that. I have generally figured out how to attach ragdolls to objects, and I will post a detailed answer when I have time.

Comment: I still have problems though (like ragdolls flying around the room), so I'll write something if nothing else pops up.

Comment: If you have a good idea that works but has some other issues you could edit that into your question to maybe get some more specific help.

Comment: For completeness' sake, I answered the original question. As to your 'current' problem: it might have to do with remnant information in your *phys_constraintsystem*, maybe try removing that?

Answer (score 1):

To attach a ragdoll to another object, you need two entities: a *prop_ragdoll*, and a *phys_ragdollconstraint*. The latter gives you the additional opportunity to attach the ragdoll to another nameable entity (used in cases where the ragdoll's parent is moving or can be moved, I presume), but this is optional.

- Place the ragdoll (and its parent), and position the *phys_ragdollconstraint* as the point where the ragdoll is hanging from, like an imaginary nail.
- Give the *prop_ragdoll* a unique name.
- Go into the proporties of the *phys_ragdollconstraint*, and fill in the name of the ragdoll entity under 'Entity 1' (and that of the optional parenting entity under 'Entity 2').

[image]

- Compile, and enjoy the show in-game.

[image]